# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: linq-to-sql

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    var doesrequestExist = cxt.Friends.FirstOrDefault(u => (u.User_Id == incID) &&
         (u.Friend_UserId == (list.ElementAt(i).userid)) && 
         (u.Request_Status == 0 || u.Request_Status == 1));
    if (doesrequestExist != null)
    {
    }
```

i am getting error at "list.ElementAt(i).userid"
error:
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Edit:

By removing the convert.toint32 in above query getting:
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'FriendsList ElementAt[FriendsList](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[FR_Network.FR_Network+FriendsList], Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: are you trying to convert an integer using your Convert.ToInt32??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exclude  Convert.ToInt32(list.ElementAt(i).userid)) from your linq.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    int friendId = Convert.ToInt32(list.ElementAt(i).userid);
    var doesrequestExist = cxt.Friends.FirstOrDefault(u => (u.User_Id == incID) &&
                                                           (u.Friend_UserId == friendId &&
                                                           (u.Request_Status == 0 || u.Request_Status == 1));

    if (doesrequestExist != null)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'FriendsList ElementAt[FriendsList](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[FR_Network.FR_Network+FriendsList], Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: thanks i got solution take one varieable and assign the value of list.element(i).userid before the statement.